# Proxmox 3 cluster configuration disappeared

Tags: openvz, proxmox, hypervisor

We have been running a Proxmox VE version 3 system for some time without issues. Abruptly, the `/etc/cluster/cluster.conf` file disappeared, `pve-cluster` and `cman` fell over and containers became inaccesible. We recreated the cluster configuration with `pvecm create newcluster` and it found the previous container images and booted them. However, the OpenVZ command line tools are now non-functional. For example, `vzlist -a` on the hypervisor reports 'Container(s) not found'. Has anyone else seen this behavious and, if a solution was found, what was it?

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same situation.
Client stored these files on an encrypted drive over mdadm and did a hard reset.
After that the /etc/pve folder was gone.

Maybe that's your case too. I guess Proxmox stores some configuration in memory and does not handle hard resets well. Especially if you have complex storage like LVM + LUKS + MDADM. Instead trying to fix corrupted data it removes all configuration leaving container's private data.

Comment: We're using a pretty generic RAID system. /etc/pve was still there, but cluster and container configuration was gone.